# Problems using Rooms on Android Studios

Tags: android, android-room

I'm doing an app for final project and I have a strange case using rooms.

When I was uninstall the aplication and I install again the app the database is the same at before, it didn't clean all the information of database. But when I cleaned the information by the manual way (on options of android) it works with a new database.

If anyone can know the problem, this database works very good yesterday.

Thanks.

Comment: I've seen this problem with old Huawei phones. Are you using one of them?

Comment: No, I use Xiaomi Redmi Note 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In manifest, inside application tag make the allowBackup false.

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

It is issue due to backup i think.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works perfectly.
I had allowBackup="true", so yes, that's was the issue.